# Getting TypeError while parsing pdf to json using pdf2json

Tags: node.js

I am new to node js i want to parse pdf data to json.
I have kept my pdf file in public directory but getting error as TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function
Can you guys please help?

```
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require("fs");
const PDFParser = require("pdf2json");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.get("/", function(req, res) {

    let pdfParser = new PDFParser(this,1);

    pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataError", errData => console.error(errData.parserError) );
    pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataReady", pdfData => {
        fs.writeFile("sample.json", JSON.stringify(pdfData));
        res.send(JSON.stringify(pdfData));
    });

    pdfParser.loadPDF('./public/sample.pdf');
});
app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this, I think it's not finding your PDF file properly.

```
PDFParser.pdf2json('./public/sample.pdf', function (error, pdf) {
    if(error != null){
        console.log(error);
    }else{
        console.log(JSON.stringify(pdf));
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi 
I am getting error as PDFParser.pdf2json is not a function.
I guess it is able to find the PDF file but getting error as 
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function

Answer (score 0):

Hi i got my answer as i was missing my callback function
Below id the modified code.

```
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require("fs");
const PDFParser = require("pdf2json");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.get('/home', function(req, res) {

    let pdfParser = new PDFParser(this,1);

    pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataError", errData => console.error(errData.parserError) );
    pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataReady", pdfData => {
        fs.writeFile("sample.json",JSON.stringify(pdfData),function(err,pdfData){
            return JSON.stringify(pdfData)
        });
        res.send(JSON.stringify(pdfData));
    });

    pdfParser.loadPDF('./public/sample.pdf');
});
app.listen(3000)
```